# Div height inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jquery plugin for my own datagrid. The problem I'm facing is a clipping of one div inside another div. I need the last div to fill the remaining space, and I would like to make it without js/jquery to calculate the height if possible. I don't even need compatibility with IE or firefox, just chrome.

Here a demostration of the problem:
http://jsbin.com/ubiniy/1

As you can see, the scrollbar at the bottom is not visible. With 92% height it's visible at some dimensions, but no others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work fine when you put it in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FHRb4/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it just seems to work fine but if you change the first "overflow:hidden" to "overflow:auto" you'll see the previously hidden (cut off) part.

Comment: The table is horizontally very long, the scrollbar you see it's just a small overflow of the page, not the scrollbar of the div containing the table. I use jsbin to see it in fullscreen for this reason.

Comment: I need to keep the main div in overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it inherits parent's height as you declared but there's also 2 more divs for the titles so there's no room for all since it's over the 100% and it scrolls :)

---

OK here's an approach:

However it needs to be sure that title divs are one line only or you end up with wrong calculation.

If so you add this

```
    <div class="dlgrid" style="overflow: hidden;......height:700px;">

    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div>Title 2</div>
    <div class="dlInnerDiv" style="overflow:auto;">....
```

css:

```
div.title{
  line-height:20px;
}
div.title + div{
  line-height:18px;
}
```

or

```
div.title{
   height:20px;
}
div.title + div{
   height:18px;
}
```

In that case you have 700-20-18 = 662 or what ever heights you give to those
so all is left is to:

```
div.dlInnerDiv{
    max-height:662px;
 }
```

Also you need to reset all unwanted margins and paddings like

```
div.dlgrid,div.dlgrid div{
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;
}
```

or whatever value you want but take it in consideration when summing the height above because the vertical of these have influence on it in each of the elements participating.

I hope I've understood and this is what you're after http://jsbin.com/ubiniy/23 :)

Keep in mind that this resolves only that particular issue and you might and up with undesired behavior so I do not recommend any approach like this of fixing height in dynamic content and depending on a specific case of circumstances.

My advice is to have a look how other people have solved this issue making grids or whaever there's no need to find the hot water all over again :)

Comment: I tend to think that "100%" is "fill all the available space", and may be this is the problem. There's is a way to tell in css "just fill the space"? I need to add divs dynamically at the top, the titles are not fixed.

Comment: There is with `height` but you don't know what is left of those 100% .There are few ways I'll write it down but then there might be other issues just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know there is a way to solve with jquery/js, but I'm trying to let the browser do the math, because the app will require many tables with many data in one screen...And I can't believe there's no way to solve this using css! :)

Comment: If you try to explain me why do you need this div to fill the height exactly but not leave it according to content I might give you and other ideas just don't get what your goal is

Comment: As I said, just a "fill-remaining-space" div. But it's clearly my error thinking that it's possible without the calculation of the heights. Thanks all of you anyway.

Comment: check out this too for something more dynamic http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `overflow:auto;` from `.dlgrid` also you can remove padding or magin to make it up to the edge.

Or if you don't want to remove the `overflow:auto;` from `.dlgrid` you can make

```
<div>Title</div>
<div>Title 2</div>

<div class="dlInnerDiv" style="overflow:auto; height:94%;">
```

to

```
<div style="height:3%;">Title</div>
<div style="height:3%;">Title 2</div>

<div class="dlInnerDiv" style="overflow:auto; height:94%;">
```

more info on maybe something that might help [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)

Comment: .dlgrid is "overflow:hidden" and I need to keep it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. It's not the solution what I'm looking for, I'm trying to avoid specifying the height of each div, and as you point this is the error. I'm looking for a "fill-the-remaining-space" solution but maybe it's doesn't exists. If no other answers appears, your answer will be the correct one...